# Apache : www.fakedomain.com works not https://fakedomain.com

Tags: apache, dns

I have apache server serving `fakedomain.com` with following vhost conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/master/public_html
    ServerName www.fakedomain.com
    ServerAlias fakedomain.com
    ServerPath /var/www/master/public_html
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/fakedomain/master-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/fakedomain/master-error.log
    #LogLevel debug

      <Directory /var/www/master/public_html>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from All
      </Directory>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(/www/.*) /www/fakedomain.com$1
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.webp -f
    RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ %1\.webp [L,T=image/webp,R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/master/public_html
    ServerName www.fakedomain.com
    ServerAlias fakedomain.com
    ServerPath /var/www/master/public_html
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/fakedomain/master-access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/fakedomain/master-error.log

    <Directory /var/www/master/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from All
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(/www/.*) /www/fakedomain.com$1
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.webp -f
    RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ %1\.webp [L,T=image/webp,R]
    SSLEngine On
    ServerSignature On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/star_fakedomain_com_05_2020.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/star_fakedomain_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFIle /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

I am able to access `www.fakedomain.com` but not `https://fakedomain.com` or `http://fakedomain.com` gets `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error

This apache running on ec2 and behind classic ELB. `www.fakedomain.com` & `fakedomain.com` are  **A** record in DYN dns.

I have DNS record for `www.fakedomain.com` & `fakedomain.com`. Also tried to swap `ServerName` & `ServerAlias`, but no luck. Anyone point out whats wrong here ?

Comment: What happens when you try to access domain.com? Are you actually hitting the Apache machine, or something else?

Comment: Does only https fail or does http fail as well ? Also, I did not quite understand the last paragraph, "Everything works fine when ...." ?

Comment: Corrected  my question

Comment: You mentioned that you tried swapping `ServerName ` and `ServerAlias`. Did `http://fakedomain.com` work when you swapped?

Comment: Do you have DNS A-record with blank name? www.fakedomain.com and fakedomain.com should be different DNS records. Additionally did you check your local hosts file if you have fakedomain.com there set up correctly?

Comment: `This apache running on ec2 and behind classic ELB. www.fakedomain.com & fakedomain.com are A record in DYN dns.` You should not use an A record to target an ELB, use a CNAME

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a self signed cert or godaddy /paid  cert?
One more thing is you have redirect on configuration.

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(/www/.*) /www/fakedomain.com$1
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

You can remove all these lines for testing purpose and then it will work with www and non www
it will  show cert warning if it i sself signed.

Answer (score 1):

**"Sorry i can't post comment i don't have enough reputation "**

I have tested your configuration in my environnement and it works for me , i can access with www and without it.

can you try nslookup [www.fakedomain.com](http://www.fakedomain.com)
and nsllookup  fakedomain.com

it may be a dns propagation problem, or your dns cache is stale with high ttl , or you entered the wrong ip for fakedomain.com